# text field and button in same line

Tags: html, css

I want to put text field and button on the same line. 
I used display: inline; but it's not working. Where am i making a mistake?

```css
.listBar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 210px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
}

#add {
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

#add,
#input {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='listBar'>
  <h2 class='header' style='margin:5px'> List </h2>
  <input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title">
  <button id='add'> Add </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try display: flex -> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @MrBuggy, not working...

Comment: Take a look on my answer below. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the floats to do that, your input has a width of 100% that's why display inline didn't work, And the h2 is also block by default so you need to set it's display to inline or inline-block as well

```css
.listBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 210px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 14px;  
}

#add {
    color: black;
    border: none;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
   
}

#add, #input {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='listBar'>
<h2 class='header' style='margin:5px'> List </h2>
<input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title">
<button id='add'> Add </button>
```

Comment: but what if i want the width 100%? is there any way to do this?

Comment: I thinks he still want's the title to be above the field and button...He only writes that he would like to have the field and button eacht to other not the title...

Comment: if the input take 100% of the parent's width, there will be no room for the button.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa we can increase the length of the text field by increasing the width of the main div class element.

Comment: You don't understand, now do you ? 100% width to the child means take the parent's width, increasing the parent's width, will just increase the inputs width, like you did nothing

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have width: 100% on the input. It makes it take all the place and there is none left for your button. It will work if you remove the width there or set it to auto. Also, be careful with the second float, that one should be right, not left.

```
.listBar{
position: absolute;
left: 40px;
top: 210px;
box-sizing: border-box;}

#input{
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
background-color: aliceblue;
padding: 14px;
float: left;}

#add{
color: whitesmoke;
border: none;
background-color: inherit;
padding: 14px 20px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;}

#add, #input{
display: inline;}
```

Comment: Thank you to whomever downvoted me for no reason. Do please say why in the future. Or better yet, downvote only if the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Same on my question below.... And he also writes it's not correct, but it show's the same output like all other answers which seem to be correct...

Comment: Yes, someone is downvoting answers for no reason. And it can't be Jaizzi because he/she doesn't have enough points for that. So it's one of the other 2 persons whom answered this question. Shame on them.

Comment: @Tina and MrBuggy I didn't do that -_-

Comment: Here is an upvote to compensate your no-reason-downvote, I prefer your solution to the MrBuggy's one, because I agree with you and proposed something similar at first. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `input` takes `width: 100%;` of its parent. So there is no more room for a button on its side.

Here is a working snippet with comments:
(That's how I'll do to correct the problem if it was for myself)

```css
body { /* Added only for snippet */
  background: #ddd;
}

.listBar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #bbb; /* Added only for snippet */
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px; /* Modified only for snippet */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input {
  width: auto; /* Modified, you could also simply remove this line */
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
}

#add {
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right; /* Floating on the right */
}
```

```html
<div class='listBar'>
  <h2 class='header' style='margin:5px'> List </h2>
  <input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title">
  <button id='add'> Add </button>
</div>
```

---

Second proposal after comments:
(That's not what I'll do, but that's funny anyway!)

You could play with the `transform` property to move the element:

```css
body { 
  background-color: #ddd; /* Added only for snippet */
}

.listBar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #bbb; /* Added only for snippet */
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px; /* Modified only for snippet */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
}

#add {
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right; /* Floating on the right */
  transform: translate(100%, -50%); /* Added with funny values, just for demo. Waiting for your answer to my comment. :) */
}
```

```html
<div class='listBar'>
  <h2 class='header' style='margin:5px'> List </h2>
  <input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title">
  <button id='add'> Add </button>
</div>
```

Note that currently, because of the `padding` of the `input`, the input goes outside of its parent.
You may want to correct that.

Documentation about `transform`: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp
When using `translate()` with percentages, it takes a percentage of the size of the element.
It's quite handy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but what if i want the width 100%? is there any way to do this?

Comment: @jaizijutt I've edited. Back to an input with 100% width, do you want the button outside of the parent?

Comment: That looks like my first answer, more or less the float direction, which doesn't change a lot the display... You shouldn't have needed to post your own answer. ;)

Comment: you are wrong:). float direction did the trick here. Anyways Thanks a lot :) .

Answer (score 0):

It was right that if the input text field takes 100% of the parent's width, there will be no room for the button. In addition, there is no need of **display: inline**. You can put the text field and a button in the same line just by adding the **float: left** in both elements classes and by increasing the width of the main div class element :) .....

```
.listBar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 210px;
    width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.header {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: left; 
}

/* add button */
#add{
    color: whitesmoke;
    border: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;    
}
#add:hover{
    background-color: rgb(85, 78, 78);
}

/* input text field */
#input{
    width: 75%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 14px;
    float: left;
}
```

[here is snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbQPT.jpg)

Comment: .listBar is 30% of which width?

Comment: @TakitIsy it is the parent's width. if we increase the width of a parent element then we can increase the child's width as well.

Answer (score -1):

Put a wrapper around the `input` and `button` and than use `display: flex;`

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Did this help?

```css
.listBar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.listBar__forms {
  display: flex;
}

#input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px;
}

#add {
  color: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='listBar'>
  <h2 class='header' style='margin:5px'> List </h2>
  <div class="listBar__forms">
    <input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title">
    <button id='add'> Add </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @jaizijutt So what is your goal? So you write you would like to put the input and buttom on the same line, so in a row? In your code they are in a column below each to other (first title, than field and than button). With this solution above, the field and button are in a row? Maybe you have to scroll down when opening the snippet so you can see it...If this is not what you are looking for, please describe it bether or show us a screenshot...

Comment: @jaizijutt take a look again, I removed the top on the listBar so it is visible directly when opening snippet. And I also removed some useless code for your... I think this is the right solution...